# How can I set the spinner item to right side?

Tags: android, layout

Could you help me, how can I set the spinner item to right side, because now is align to right. In addition I tried to change align to right, but didn't work.

In design view:

[image: https://imgur.com/nzHcxS0 "Actual Design View"]

XML version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumberField"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerNumberFieldUnits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center">
    </Spinner>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: because you never used relative layout . In linear layout, there is NO parameters like align parent right or align right .Linear layout are stacked one after the other. checked the below link.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. I just had to write  android:layout_weight to 0, this idea is better than place to right. Ty @jesu